# Java Get Value from Object by Key Name

Tags: java, json, object, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have retrieved an object from Firebase and would like to access the values of it using the name of each field I would like the value for.  In javascript, this would be something as simple as `myObject.name` to retrieve the name in the object.

How can I do the equivalent in Java?

```java
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
userId = user.getUid();

ValueEventListener myObjectListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.i(TAG, "getting data");
        Object myObject = dataSnapshot.getValue();

        Log.v(TAG, myObject.toString()); 
        // Outputs: {name= "john doe", hair="brown", isStudent=true, age=12} 

        // HERE is where I would like to get the name.
        // DOES NOT work. Have also attempted things like
        // myObject.getString("name"), etc.
        myObject.getClass().getFieldName("name") 
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
};

mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).addValueEventListener(myObjectListener);
```

Comment: `myObject.getName()` doesn't work? or if name is public `myObject.name`

Comment: Are you asking how to use reflection?

Comment: I've never used Firebase. But reading the javadoc makes this quite simple: https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/DataSnapshot.html#getValue-java.lang.Class-, https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/DataSnapshot.html#getValue--

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Map<String, Object> user = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
String name = (String) user.get("name");
String hair = (String) user.get("hair");
long age    = (Long)   user.get("age");
...
```

*If* you have a [properly defined](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/DataSnapshot.html#getValue-java.lang.Class-) `User` class, than this would work even better:

```java
User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
String name = user.getName();
String hair = user.getHair();
...
```

Finally, there is a third option as well (using [`DataSnapshot.child(String)`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/DataSnapshot.html#child-java.lang.String-) method):

```java
String name = (String) dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue();
String hair = (String) dataSnapshot.child("hair").getValue();
...
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks @Paulo Mattos.  Much appreciated.  The first option worked perfectly and was necessary in my case versus the second option since the attributes of the object can be different (i.e. `hair` not existing) though I didn't think to mention that at first (my bad there).  Thanks again

Comment: @Rbar Nice! Glad to help ;)

Comment: one suggested edit is that `String age = (String) user.get("age")` crashed as I attempted to typecast it from a long to a string, but changing this to `string.valueOf(user.get("age"))` worked like a charm and still worked for strings like `getName` and `getHair`

Comment: @Rbar ...another solution would be to typecast to `Long` instead ;)

Answer (score 1):

It works for me Mehul.

```
String email = (String) ((LinkedHashMap) responseEntity.getBody().getPayload()).get("emailAddress");
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you get object "o", and you want to get the value of a field name "userName".

`(String) ((LinkedHashMap) o).get("userName")`

Comment: `Object o` has no method `get()`. `Cannot find symbol`

Comment: Typecasting is there. LinkedHashMap has a function get(), if the key userName is present it will give the value.